# MATLAB - trying to run a loop to estimate a threshold for S-shaped curves

Tags: matlab, for-loop, unique, threshold

I fitted a sigmoid shaped curve to individual datasets (n = 53). The S-shaped curve has 101 datapoints.
I've attached an example picture for one subject (and 2 conditions) [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZQeB.jpg). I'm trying to estimate x when y = 50. I can run this on individual datasets but am struggling to run the loop.

The matrices cgsx and cgft are 53 x 101 in size. The reason why I have to use the function "unique" is because for subject 8 the curve is very steep.

For the single subject this code seems to do the correct thing:

```
load cgft
load cgsx

nsub = 8; % for example

[~, ind1] = unique(cgft); % ind = index of first occurrence of a repeated value
yc(nsub, :) = interp1(cgft(ind1), cgsx(ind1), .50, 'linear','extrap');
```

I have tried various variations of the loop for all 53 subjects and just cannot get it to spit out the correct values. Any advice greatly appreciated.

One of many attempts is below:

```
load cgft
load cgsx

subjects = [1:53];
nbsubjects = length(subjects);

for nsubs = 1:nbsubjects
    nsub = subjects(nsubs);

   [~, ind1] = unique(cgft(nsub, :));
    yc(nsub, :) = interp1(cgft(ind1(nsub, :)), cgsx(ind1(nsub, :)), .50, 'linear','extrap');

end
```